# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) while using OpenCV in Processing language

Tags: java, opencv, processing

My Processing code is below.

```
import hypermedia.video.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

OpenCV opencv;

int width = 320;
int height = 240;

void setup() {

size( 320, 240 ); //set window size

opencv = new OpenCV( this ); //setup openCV
opencv.capture( width, height ); // open video stream
opencv.cascade( OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE_ALT );
}

void draw(){
opencv.read();
image(opencv.image(), 0, 0);
Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect( 1.2, 2, OpenCV.HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 40, 40 );
noFill();
  stroke(255,0,0);
  for( int i=0; i<faces.length; i++ ) {
    rect( faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height );
  }
}
```

This code works for few seconds then an exception occurs.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d961b22, pid=232, tid=4008
#
# JRE version: 6.0_33-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.8-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa1b22]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\processing-2.0b7\hs_err_pid232.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Hi @vishnu - does this code throw the same exception on other machines?  have you run memtest (http://www.memtest.org/) on your machine to make sure it's not corrupted RAM.  I had something similar happen to me and it was bad RAM on my desktop machine.

Comment: I ran this code on my friend's laptop and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is a memory allocation issue with opencv_core.CvMemStorage. this is a class that's not exposed in your library. i am having the same problem. I'm using javacv (directly, not javacvpro) because i want to run multiple haar cascades (you can load only one with javacvpro or the older hypermedia.video.*). if i run ALL of them on EACH frame, i'm good. if i run a different detector on each frame (and then cycle thru the detectors again), i get this error after a few cycles.

the snippet below FAILS, but it is what i want to do (process each subsequent frame with a different detector):

```
// Using JavaCV directly, not JavaCVPro!
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
String cascades[] = {
  "haarcascade_eye.xml",            // 0
  "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml",    // 1
  "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"      // 2
}
int detectors[] = {1,3};
// haar detectors to use

String cascPath = "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/";
// preload multiple classifiers. can do this with javacvpro, not with javacv or hypermedia.video.*

void haarSetup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < detectors.length; i++) {
      String classifierFile = cascPath+cascades[detectors[i]];
      classifier[i] = 
        new opencv_objdetect.CvHaarClassifierCascade(opencv_core.cvLoad(classifierFile));
    }
    storage = opencv_core.CvMemStorage.create();
    opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage(storage); // is this needed? couldn't hurt, right?
}

// contains list of preloaded haar cascades. code not included here...
opencv_core.CvSeq features[] = new opencv_core.CvSeq[detectors.length];
int whichHaar = 0;

// run one cascade per frame, then cycle through them.
void processHaars(PImage piz) {
  // convert to IplImage...  
  BufferedImage imgBuf = (BufferedImage) piz.getNative();    
  opencv_core.IplImage iplImgOut=opencv_core.IplImage.createFrom(imgBuf);
  // do one haar cascade per invocation.
  int ii = whichHaar;
  features[ii] = opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(iplImgOut, classifier[ii], storage, 1.1, 3, opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
  whichHaar++;
  if (whichHaar >= detectors.length){
    whichHaar = 0;
    // is THIS causing the problem??
    opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage(storage);
  }
}
```

this snippet WORKS forever, but i don't want what it does (run all detectors on a single frame):

```
void processHaars(PImage piz) {
// convert to IplImage...  
BufferedImage imgBuf = (BufferedImage) piz.getNative();    
opencv_core.IplImage iplImgOut=opencv_core.IplImage.createFrom(imgBuf);

for (ii=0; ii<detectors.length; ii++)
    faces[ii] = opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(iplImgOut, classifier[ii], storage, 1.1, 3, opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage(storage);
}
```

If i find a full solution, I'll post it.